# Phonegap PushPlugin can't receive notifications ios

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am developing a Phonegap application for both Android and iOS and would like to enable push notifications for both.

The app is using the Phonegap plugin PushPlugin which sets it to receive notification for both Android and iOS.

I am having issue with the **iOS** version of the app. When running it, I get the screen asking if I want to allow the app to receive notifications, I select yes then I receive a **device token** which is then used on the server side to send the notification to the selected device.  This was a good indication that the **Phonegap plugin was working**.

Server side, I am using AmazonSNS to send the notifications. (Java code of this can be downloaded [here.](https://s3.amazonaws.com/codesamples/sns/latest/snsmobilepush.zip))

With AmazonSNS I need to pass in:

- certificate (created in the online iOS development center)
- private key (exported from the certificate)
- device token (from PushPlugin)

to send the notification.

I followed [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) detailed tutorial on how to get the app id, certificate, private key and provisioning profile all set up.

The problem is, after sending the notification, not only does the app not receive the notification, but sending the notification doesn't error or give me any feedback as to what *might* have went wrong.

I'll also point out, the Android version of the app is successfully receiving notifications using the same java code.

Any advice on what the issue here might be would be great.

Thanks

Comment: [This might have some helpful troubleshooting insight](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html), it's from Apple's documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to work out what the problem was.

In my server-side plugin, I was trying to connect to **APNS** directly, but what I should of been doing was connecting to **APNS_SANDBOX**.